# Checkbox positions in picture

Tags: html, css, user-interface, checkbox, frontend

How is it possible to drop a few checkboxes inside a picture at a specific position?

It would be very nice if I can drop the 11 checkboxes at the led position of the palm picture.

[LED-Palm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMXEe.jpg)

```
<div class="container">
  <img alt="palm" src="palme.png" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led3" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led4" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led5" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led6" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led7" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led8" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led9" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led10" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led11" />
</div>
```

[The idea goes back to Christian Hascheks LED-Cactus.](https://blog.haschek.at/2018/raspberry-pi-controlled-cactus.html)

Comment: You will need to use absolute positioning for the checkboxes. There is no automated way to do this: you will need to determine the `top` and `left` positions of each checkbox manually.

Comment: thx for the answer ;)

Comment: Note: the `<img>` and `<input>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container > input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
}

#led1 {
  top: 70px;
  left: 142px;
}

#led2 {
  top: 39px;
  left: 230px;
}

#led3 {
  top: 84px;
  left: 257px;
}

#led4 {
  top: 154px;
  left: 263px;
}

#led5 {
  top: 132px;
  left: 188px;
}

#led6 {
  top: 145px;
  left: 75px;
}

#led7 {
  top: 195px;
  left: 92px;
}

#led8 {
  top: 231px;
  left: 150px;
}

#led9 {
  top: 251px;
  left: 215px;
}

#led10 {
  top: 364px;
  left: 206px;
}

#led11 {
  top: 472px;
  left: 179px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img alt="palm" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMXEe.jpg" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led1" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led2" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led3" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led4" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led5" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led6" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led7" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led8" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led9" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led10" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="led" id="led11" />
</div>
```

Comment: thx for the fast answer ;) one question, where I must drop the content of ".container {..." ... in a CSS-File, in the HTML-code?! thx

Comment: You can add it In a CSS-file or in HTML but it need to have
`<style>{code}</style>`